# vTiger lead update

Tags: php, api, vtiger

I have used vTiger WebForms module to insert new leads inside the vTiger system, 
now I need to perform an update for these leads - is there any to do this operation?

I did not find any reference for this operation...

Answer (score 0):

Look at Web services documentation.

May be you have to change index file in webforms folder and call appropriate api's over there.
Before that take up of your files and i think you need to register an that operation before you do any CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

You must download and read documentation to make connection via web services with vtiger crm to perform update/delete/insert download from here:

http://forge.vtiger.com/frs/?group_id=181